# std::thread constructor sometimes does not return (vc++ 2014 preview)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, visual-c++

I am having a problem in my C++ HTTP server where sometimes creating a new thread to handle the client request does not return.  I have tried everything I can think of (limit the number of concurrent threads), and aside from limiting the number of threads to 1, it does not fix.

This happens in another program of mine as well, also using VC++ 2014 Preview compiler.

This is some example code where the problem happens.  I have verified that it sometimes prints out "About to create new thread..." but fails to print out the next "Detaching new thread..." or "Ending accept..."

Occasionally, after a couple minutes, or when I apply some outside influence (such as pausing the application in the debugger, which reveals the code to appear to currently be in the thread constructor), the program will eventually start running correctly again.  I have also verified that other threads always continue to perform correctly at all times.

The threadcount never makes it past 6 or 7, even when I refresh a local webpage with ~20 images on it as fast as I can, so I don't think the problem has anything to do with having too many threads at once.

The only thing I can think of is "threadCount" is lying, as I am decrementing it at the end of the thread function, but the thread still technically exists at the time it is decremented.  But I do not think this is the issue because sometimes thread construction will hang even after only refreshing a page twice, and my test machine has 8 hardware threads.

Blocking when threadCount is greater than 1 or 2 appears to be reliable but probably isn't actually.  Limiting to 4 is not reliable.

```
atomic_int threadCount = 0;
bool Server::checkForNewConnection()
{
    sockaddr clientAddress;
    socklen_t clientAddressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
    fd_set readSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    FD_SET(this->serverSocket, &readSet);

    const auto clientSocket = accept(this->serverSocket, &clientAddress, &clientAddressLength);

    cout << "Incremented threadcount: " << ++threadCount << endl;

    if (clientSocket < 0 || clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        closesocket2(clientSocket);
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in* add2;
    add2 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(&clientAddress);

    const string clientAddressString(inet_ntoa(add2->sin_addr));

    cout << "About to create new thread..." << endl;
    thread serverThread(&ForkThread, this, clientSocket, clientAddressString, false);
    cout << "Detaching new thread..." << endl;
    serverThread.detach();
    cout << "Ending accept..." << endl;

    return true;
```

}

Comment: Can you try it with a production/stable compiler release?

Comment: @JohnZwinck  I can try it with g++.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I tried it with VC++2013 and was unable to get it to fail.  But the extent of my current ability to test this is mashing f5 in my browser as fast as I can.

Comment: Well if it works in VC++ 2013 you should probably report it as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: What is `ForkThread`? Is it a function or a class? I am thinking that maybe something is wrong with your thread entry point. Does the newly started thread print a lot of messages so that "Detaching new thread..." appears in the console output much later than "About to create new thread..."?